# Get property of person Alfresco in JAVA

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I'm using Alfresco 5.1 Community, and i'm trying to get a property value of a current person logged for example, in the user I have:

```
 "{http://www.someco.org/model/people/1.0}customProperty"
```

How can I obtain this in java?

Is a custom property, so, in http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/people it does not appear. How can I do this?

I try this to obtain at least nodeRef:

```
protected ServiceRegistry getServiceRegistry() {
        ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl config = Context.getProcessEngineConfiguration();
        if (config != null) {
            // Fetch the registry that is injected in the activiti spring-configuration
            ServiceRegistry registry = (ServiceRegistry) config.getBeans().get(ActivitiConstants.SERVICE_REGISTRY_BEAN_KEY);

            if (registry == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Service-registry not present in ProcessEngineConfiguration beans, expected ServiceRegistry with key" + ActivitiConstants.SERVICE_REGISTRY_BEAN_KEY);
            }

            return registry;
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("No ProcessEngineConfiguration found in active context");
    }

    public void writeToCatalina() {
        PersonService personService = getServiceRegistry().getPersonService();
        System.out.println("test");
        String name = AuthenticationUtil.getFullyAuthenticatedUser();
        System.out.println(name);
        NodeRef personRef = personService.getPerson(name);
        System.out.println(personRef);
    }
```

But I got:

> No ProcessEngineConfiguration found in active context

Help me !

Answer (score 2):

You can query Alfresco using CMIS and call the API:

```
GET /alfresco/service/api/people/{userName}.
```

For first you can define the method to create the session CmisSession:

```
public Session getCmisSession() {

    logger.debug("Starting: getCmisSession()");

    // default factory implementation
    SessionFactory factory = SessionFactoryImpl.newInstance();
    Map<String, String> parameter = new HashMap<String, String>();

    // connection settings
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.ATOMPUB_URL, url + ATOMPUB_URL);
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.BINDING_TYPE, BindingType.ATOMPUB.value());
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.AUTH_HTTP_BASIC, "true");
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.USER, username);
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.PASSWORD, password);
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.OBJECT_FACTORY_CLASS, "org.alfresco.cmis.client.impl.AlfrescoObjectFactoryImpl");

    List<Repository> repositories = factory.getRepositories(parameter);

    return repositories.get(0).createSession();
}
```

Then execute the query (this method returns more than one result, you probably need to change it):

```
public void doQuery(String cql, int maxItems) {

    Session cmisSession = getCmisSession();

    OperationContext oc = new OperationContextImpl();
    oc.setMaxItemsPerPage(maxItems);

    ItemIterable<QueryResult> results = cmisSession.query(cql, false, oc);

    for (QueryResult result : results) {
        for (PropertyData<?> prop : result.getProperties()) {
            logger.debug(prop.getQueryName() + ": " + prop.getFirstValue());
        }

    }

}
```

If you need to get the token, use this:

```
public String getAuthenticationTicket() {

    try {   

        logger.info("ALFRESCO: Starting connection...");

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("user", username);
        params.put("password", password);
        Source result = restTemplate.getForObject(url + AFMConstants.URL_LOGIN_PARAM, Source.class, params);

        logger.info("ALFRESCO: CONNECTED!");

        XPathOperations xpath = new Jaxp13XPathTemplate();          
        return xpath.evaluateAsString("//ticket", result);
    }
    catch (RestClientException ex) {
        logger.error("FATAL ERROR - Alfresco Authentication failed - getAuthenticationTicket() - "  + ex );
        return null;
    }       
    catch (Exception ex) {          
        logger.error("FATAL ERROR - Alfresco Authentication failed - getAuthenticationTicket() - "  + ex );
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: But I want to get the parameter of the current user logged, without give any information (user, pass). How can I make this?

Comment: @PetterS I'll reply asap

Comment: Thanks @AndreaGirardi! :)

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11156671/get-current-user-name-inside-called-webscript

Comment: And how can I get personService? I make something like this... But not works. I put in the question edit.

Answer (score 1):

You need to obtain your user noderef using [this API](http://docs.alfresco.com/community/references/dev-services-person.html) then access its properties [this way](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/NodeRef_cookbook#Reading_a_property_of_a_node)!

---

**Edit :** You need to inject service registry on your bean!

Comment: But I want to get the parameter of the current user logged, without give any information (user, pass). In this case, you create a person and you obtain the nodeRef through that. But if I want current user how can I make this?

Answer (score 0):

```
String name = AuthenticationUtil.getFullyAuthenticatedUser()
```

You can use this. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Yes for the current user. But and the property?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you current logged in user name and detail.

```
        String name = AuthenticationUtil.getFullyAuthenticatedUser();
        System.out.println("Current user:"+name);
        PersonService personService=serviceRegistry.getPersonService();
        NodeRef node=personService.getPerson(name);
        NodeService nodeService=serviceRegistry.getNodeService();
        Map<QName, Serializable> props=nodeService.getProperties(node);

        for (Entry<QName, Serializable> entry : props.entrySet())
        {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
        }
```